# Как в Mysql БД обновлять 1 столбец с данными при условии, что каждая строка уникальна, а данные обновляются каждые 5 сек

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, update

Столкнулся с проблемой обновления данных в БД MySQL. Пишу на Python, большого опыта нет, я только учусь... Вкратце о проблеме: программа получает данные по текущим ценам акций по API, их фильтрует и добавляет в таблицу в БД. С этой частью все понятно, но далее мне требуется чтобы строк не было бесконечное количество, а количество строк соответствовало числу акций (пробовал через UNIQUE, строки да, уникальны, но обновлять их не хочет никак), в последствии эти строки и должны обновляться, точнее 1 столбец в каждой строке. Как это реализовать я не знаю, у кого есть какие мысли, прошу мне помочь! Заранее благодарен.

Строка имеет вид: id name (уникально) price (нужно обновлять)
Если акций к примеру 5 видов, то таблица будет вида:

```
id1 А price 55
id2 B price 43
id3 C price 21
id4 D price 64
id5 E price 98
```

Comment: INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE в помощь

Comment: В каких-то БД ещё `MERGE` был на эту тему, кажется

Comment: @CrazyElf В каких-то еще UPSERT есть

Comment: Используйте не INSERT INTO, а REPLACE INTO.

Comment: @Akina зачем? он при встрече дубля удаляет и вставляет новую

Comment: @teran Судя по описанию, большинство данных будет вызывать обновление. В таких условиях REPLACE более выгоден.

Comment: @Akina так он каскады ведь вызовет и триггеры небось, и инкрементный id изменится, если был (в смысле у записи "обновляемой")

Comment: @teran Если там есть триггеры, то вообще надо очень серьёзно думать, что использовать - INSERT ODKU и REPLACE при обнаружении дублей вызывают выполнение разных триггеров. https://dbfiddle.uk/qBA0G0uB Вот при наличии ссылок по ID - да, проблема. Хотя не знаю, зачем первичный ID при уникальном NAME - коды у акций короткие.